# Detection of 100px area differences in noise pictures

Tags: matlab, image-processing, compare, imagemagick

Assume you have one picture which is

[image]

where you want alert if the area/contrast/color difference is more than 100 pixels in square meter. 
So the algorithm say **yes** to this picture but **no** to the following picture
[image]

Possible tools are

- ImageMagick's *compare* but I do not find this the best way
- Matlab - there are functions builtin here but I do no know which

### Output from Shai's code in Matlab R2014b

[image]

[image]

Some stages after this

- find the correct threshold for the separation of processes
- separate the processes like described by Shai
- do decision making - count the amount of white areas in squares so long as one 100px area is found

**How can you pick 100px area differences among two files?**

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. You show a picture but do not say what you expect to find in it. What is the 100px - the area of something? Or do you mean a brightness difference of 100 grey levels?

Comment: 100px is 100 pixels. To find areas larger than this where area difference.

Comment: @Masi: It may appear very obvious to you, but it isn't to the rest of the world. What should be the output of the analysis of the picture you linked. Should we find that there are two different areas, one bright and one dark (both being .larger than 100-by-100 pixels)?

Comment: @jonas Yes, notificartion that just observation. No need differentiate colours. Yes, two different areas. I leave hands open bcause contrast may not be the best way to go.

Comment: I simplified the question. Only the Yes/No answer enough. Only these pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use aggressive average filter to get rid of the noise and the threshold:

```
%// read image and convert to single channel gray-scale:
img1 = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDoUe.png');
img1 = rgb2gray(img1);
img2 = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOs0w.png');
img2 = rgb2gray(img2);

%// use aggressive average filter
f1 = imfilter( img1, ones(11)/121, 'symmetric');
f2 = imfilter( img2, ones(11)/121, 'symmetric');
```

Once noise is crudely removed you can threshold the filtered images

```
bw1 = f1 > 128;
bw2 = f2 > 128;
```

The resulting thresholded images are:
[image]
I believe you can take it from here...

Comment: How can you determine the correct value of the constant (128) in the inequality (f1 > 128)? How much can this threshold maximally vary in gray scale? I think much. So the first thing should be for the algorithm to find the correct threshold.

Comment: @Masi I do not think the threshold vary. If I understand your question correctly you are trying to separate a dark region from a bright one only that you have quite a lot of noise. The large filter should take care of the noise and leave you with quite a simple decision.

Comment: I started to compare your answer to Mark's answer. How much is your threshold in percentages? Does your *imfilter* have any blur component? What are the benefits of having the blur or not having it?

Comment: @Masi my thershold is 50% as in Mark's solution (which is the same as mine, only implemented using ImageMagcik). `imfilter` is the blur component of the ImageMagick solution. You must have a blur or a filter to overcome the noise.

Answer (score 1):

I still do not understand your question, or what the problem is with @Shai's answer. As far as I can see, the problem is just as easily tackled with ImageMagick in exactly the same way as Shai suggests, so nor do I see why you believe ImageMagick is the wrong approach. Maybe you can clarify what it is that you actually seek, so we can both try and assist you further.

Anyway, for now, I would go the same way with ImageMagick

```
convert input.png -blur x5 -threshold 50%  output.png
```

[image]

If you want to count the white pixels, I would clone the image and set all the pixels in the clone to black, then get ImageMagick to tell me in absolute terms how many pixels are different between the clone and the original, like this:

```
convert output.png \( +clone -evaluate set 0 \) -metric AE -compare -format "%[distortion]" info:
```

**Output**

```
89008
```

And if you want to count the black pixels, you can invert (negate) the image first, like this

```
convert output.png -negate \( +clone -evaluate set 0 \) -metric AE -compare -format "%[distortion]" info:
93414
```